# Постоянный механизм вывода уведомлений Android

Tags: android, уведомления

В общем у меня в приложении есть база данных с датами. Мне нужно чтобы приложение постоянно пару раз в день проверяло эти даты, если текущая дата совпадает с датой в базе данных то вывести определенное уведомление.

Я понимаю что мне нужен IntentService и я с ним познакомился, но всеравно пока не имею представление как это реализовать. Есть идея создать постоянный цикл и в нем проверять даты и выводить уведомления, правльно ли я мыслю? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен отдельный AlarmReceiver - он сам себя ставит в бесконечное расписание, чтобы запускать нужный нам сервис/действие. В нашем случае он бесконечно запускает UpdateService. Обратите внимание, чтобы сервис не убивался в 6-7 Андроиде, нужно перезапуск делать методом setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().

Вот рабочий пример такого ресивера:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String INTENT_ALARM_UPDATE =
            "com.example.ALARM_UPDATE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "Сработал таймер для запуска сервиса обновления");
        UpdateService.start(context, intent);
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

        // Next alarm
        schedule(context);
    }

    public static void schedule(Context context) {
        Calendar calUpdater = Calendar.getInstance();
        calUpdater.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, Constants.TIME_UPDATE);

        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(INTENT_ALARM_UPDATE);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentAlarm,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            service.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calUpdater.getTimeInMillis(),
                    pending);
        } else {
            service.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calUpdater.getTimeInMillis(), pending);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: так ну я не встречался еще с такими классами, вроде что-то понятно. Я так понимаю все что мне нужно, это написать свой код в методе onReceice?

Comment: Нет, свой код вы делаете в отдельном классе-сервисе UpdateService.
А AlarmReceiver прост обудет просыпаться по расписанию (schedule) и запускать ваш сервис обновлений.